# Two separate lines space themselves really far apart

Tags: html, css

I've created a block split into 2 sections, an image and some text.

The image aligns fine in the center, but for some reason when I use 2 lines of text, they space themselves to the `top` and `bottom` ends of its parent.

I want to try and avoid using negative margins if possible.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8rLf4qob/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="info-block">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    <span class="value">495<br /><small>New Users</small></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.info-block {
    width: 100%;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;

    .icon {
        width: 40%;
        float: left;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #27344C;
        color: white;
        height: 98px;
        line-height: 98px;
        font-size: 40px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    .value {
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #333;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 32px;

        small {
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you look properly they are not at top and bottom of parent...you have given big font size i.e. 32 px that's why it looks like it....try to increase the height of div or reduce the font size to see the difference

Comment: Thing is I dont want to reduce the font size or increase the height of the whole thing

Comment: There's no image. That is also text, if you're reffering to font-awesome. With a line height and all. Set your both "text" lines with a height of 50px and get rid of the break (br).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by adding the following attributes to your .value selector:

```
.value{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hopefully this gives you a push in the right direction.